# Fix for downloading Stock Data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I am trying to download DJIA data from Yahoo Finance using Python.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf # Fix for downloading financial data from Yahoo, as the Pyhton Yahoo API has stopped working

yf.pdr_override()

djia = pdr.get_data_yahoo("^DJI", start="2017-10-20", end="2015-10-20")
```

But I get this error

```
Auto-overriding of pandas_datareader's get_data_yahoo() is deprecated and no longer available.
```

Any other way I can download DJIA data from Yahoo?

Comment: I think they stopped the service of providing the data. Try once with quandl

Comment: Oh ho!. Any other ways of getting Index Data. A pull from Google Finance doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah try installing  quandl https://www.quandl.com/ and  `quandl.get("BCB/UDJIAD1")` may work

Answer (score 1):

```
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import datetime as dt
start = dt.datetime(2012,5,31)
end = dt.datetime(2018,5,31)
data = yf.download('DIA',start = start,end = end)
```

This code will work for dowloading DIA dat from yahoo finance.

You don't need to use pandas_datareader